# How to use parameters in Properties file (Java)

Tags: java

**propertyMsg=Invalid value in field {0} : {1}**

and I am throwing an exception like:

> **throw ServiceException.FAILURE("Invalid value in field currencyvalue : "+currencyName, "propertyMsg{currencyvalue},{"+currencyName+"}", false);**

but I'm getting output like:

> **Invalid value in field currencyvalue : {1}**

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is you are actually trying to do. Your question doesn't really make much sense to me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Store parameters in properties file in following format

Property1=value1
Property2=value2

And then use following code in java

```
FileInputStream fis=new        FileInputStream("filepath");
 Properties prop=new properties();
  Prop.load(fis);
```

And then you can use parameter by using

```
 Prop.get("parameter_name);
```